# Como obter todos os registros de uma tabela mista gerada pela herança de classes ao usar EntityFramework 6?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-6

Tenho uma estrutura de classes na seguinte forma:

```cs
public class Pessoa
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Nome {get; set;}
}

public class Membro : Pessoa
{
    public int CargoId {get; set;}
    public Cargo Cargo {get; set;}
}

public class MembroTemp : Pessoa { }
```

Meu banco de dados está com a tabela `Pessoas` agregando os dados referentes às duas classes e com isso possui o campo `Discriminator`.

[image: Como ficou a base]

Em uma tela de consulta preciso trazer os dois tipos de dados, da classe `Membro` e `MembroTemp`. E, para os registros do tipo `Membro` preciso obter o `Cargo` para então demonstrar nessa consulta.

Logo, pensei em algo como:

```cs
var items = repository.Pessoas.Include(x => x.Cargo).OrderBy(x => x.Nome);
```

Mas é claro que não dá, nem compila porque a classe `Pessoa` não possui a propriedade `Cargo`, ela é de `Membro`. Nem mesmo se eu forçar com um `Include("Cargo")` não vai funcionar, claro.

Tentei uma busca unificada em vez de fazer separado:

```cs
var membros = repository.Membros.Include(x => x.Cargo).OrderBy(x => x.Nome);  
var membrosTemp = repository.MembrosTemp.OrderBy(x => x.Nome);
```

Porque em minha `Action` realizo **filtros** e **ordenação por campos**. No caso da  ordenação eu não sei como unificar os registros mas respeitar a ordenação.

Se eu fizer requisições separadas vou acabar obtendo um resultado do tipo:

```
+-----------------------------+
|ID | Nome     | Discriminator|
+-----------------------------+
| 1 | Fulano 1 | Membro       |
| 2 | Fulano 2 | Membro       |
| 3 | Fulano 1 | MembroTemp   |
| 4 | Fulano 2 | MembroTemp   |
+-----------------------------+
```

E isso não é uma ordenação por nome perfeita.

**Como posso lidar com essa situação?**

Comment: Pode mostrar como ficaram as tabelas definidas no BD?

Comment: @ramaral, apresentando somente a tabela `Pessoas`. Vou apresentar uma imagem demonstrado!

Comment: @ramaral, desculpe a demora, e a imagem do banco foi adicionada!

Comment: `LazyLoading` está enabled ou disabled?

Comment: @ramaral, não configurei nada a respeito de `LazyLoading`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Se ficou uma herança entre essas entidades é com `OfType` a solução, e o [DbSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbset%28v=vs.113%29.aspx) só vai conter a Super Classe `Gente`. Só reforçando que em Herança o OfType é indispensável.

***Exemplo: 1 Tabela Somente (`Discriminator`)***

**Classes:**

```
public class Gente
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public String Nome { get; set; }
}    
public class GenteFisica: Gente
{
    public string Cpf { get; set; }

    public int CargoId {get;set;}        
    [ForeignKey("CargoId")]
    public virtual Cargo Cargo { get; set; }
}    
public class GenteJuridica: Gente
{
    public string Cnpj { get; set; }
    public String Ie { get; set; }
}
[Table("Cargo")]
public class Cargo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public String Nome { get; set; }
}
public class Db : System.Data.Entity.DbContext
{
    public Db()
        : base("Data Source=.\\SqlExpress;initial catalog=generics2;Integrated Security=False;User ID=sa;Password=senha;Connect Timeout=15;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False")
    {

    }
    public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<Gente> Gente {get; set;}
    public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<Cargo> Cargo { get; set; }
}
```

**Código:**

```
namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Db db = new Db();

            Cargo cargo = new Cargo();
            cargo.Nome = "Administrador";

            GenteFisica gentefisica = new GenteFisica();
            gentefisica.Nome = "Fulano Fisica 1";
            gentefisica.Cpf = "12345645600";
            gentefisica.Cargo = cargo;
            gentefisica.CargoId = cargo.Id

            GenteJuridica gentejuridica = new GenteJuridica();
            gentejuridica.Nome = "Fulano Fisica 1";
            gentejuridica.Cnpj = "12345645600-00";
            gentejuridica.Ie = "102030405060";

            db.Cargo.Add(cargo);
            db.Gente.Add(gentefisica);
            db.Gente.Add(gentejuridica);

            db.SaveChanges();

            GenteFisica gentefi = db.Gente.OfType<GenteFisica>().Where(x => x.Id == 1).FirstOrDefault();
            GenteJuridica genteju = db.Gente.OfType<GenteJuridica>().Where(x => x.Id == 2).FirstOrDefault();
            db.Dispose();

        }
    }
}
```

**Base Gerada:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Resultado:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

***Exemplo: 3 Tabelas***

Adicione nessas classes o Table do [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).Schem dessa forma

```
[Table("Gente")]
public class Gente
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public String Nome { get; set; }
}    
[Table("GenteFisica")]
public class GenteFisica: Gente
{
    public string Cpf { get; set; }

    public int CargoId {get;set;}        
    [ForeignKey("CargoId")]
    public virtual Cargo Cargo { get; set; }
}    
[Table("GenteJuridica")]
public class GenteJuridica: Gente
{
    public string Cnpj { get; set; }
    public String Ie { get; set; }
}    
[Table("Cargo")]
public class Cargo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public String Nome { get; set; }
}    
public class Db : System.Data.Entity.DbContext
{
    public Db()
        : base("Data Source=.\\SqlExpress;initial catalog=generics2;Integrated Security=False;User ID=sa;Password=senha;Connect Timeout=15;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False")
    {

    }
    public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<Gente> Gente {get; set;}
    public System.Data.Entity.DbSet<Cargo> Cargo { get; set; }
}
```

**Ele criará sua base com 4 tabelas:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

*Obs: a codificação é igual a de 1 tabela (Add, Update, Delete e Select) com o `DbSet<Gente>` para `GenteFisica` e `GenteJuridica`*

**SQL com Order By Nome - Concat - UNION ALL**

```
        **Concat**       
        //Sem o Tipo
        var resultado = db.Gente.OfType<GenteFisica>().Select(x => new
        {                
            x.Id,
            x.Nome
        }).Concat(db.Gente.OfType<GenteJuridica>().Select(g => new
        {                
            g.Id,
            g.Nome                
        })).AsQueryable();

        var resultOrdemNome = resultado.OrderBy(x => x.Nome).ToList();
```

---

```
        **Concat**
        //Com o Tipo 
        var resultado = db.Gente.OfType<GenteFisica>().Select(x => new
        {                
            x.Id,
            x.Nome, 
            Gente = "GenteFisica"
        }).Concat(db.Gente.OfType<GenteJuridica>().Select(g => new
        {                
            g.Id,
            g.Nome,
            Gente = "GenteJuridica" 
        })).AsQueryable();
        var resultOrdemNome = resultado.OrderBy(x => x.Nome).ToList();
```

---

```
        **Concat**
        //Com tipo e com Cargo quando tem 
        var resultado = db.Gente.OfType<GenteFisica>().Select(x => new
        {                
            x.Id,
            x.Nome, 
            Gente = "GenteFisica",
            Cargo = x.Cargo.Nome
        }).Concat(db.Gente.OfType<GenteJuridica>().Select(g => new
        {                
            g.Id,
            g.Nome,
            Gente = "GenteJuridica",
            Cargo = ""
        })).AsQueryable();
        var resultOrdemNome = resultado.OrderBy(x => x.Nome).ToList();
```

Comment: Vou só testar aqui se consigo manter a ordenação.

Comment: @TiagoPSilva eu to arrumando agora eu preciso entender talvez o que você deseja deixa eu colocar o cargo já te falo

Comment: O Cargo nem é tão importante. O Cargo é só um diferencial como CPF e o CNPJ. A questão é manter uma ordem pelo campo solicitado. Veja meu exemplo de ordenação, onde a idéia seria uma ordenação por Nome. Enfim, como unir, segundo o seu exemplo, `gentefi` e `genteju` e ordenar por `Nome`?

Comment: @Tiago dá uma olhada no ultimo item juntando as duas

Comment: Resolvido e aceito. +1 pela larga explicação. Muito bom! Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 2):

Se `LazyLoading` estiver enabled, que é o caso por defeito.

```
var items = repository.Pessoas.OrderBy(x => x.Nome);
```

Retorna todos os registos da tabela `Pessoas` ordenados pelo nome.

A única coisa que é necessário para ter acesso ao cargo é fazer um `cast` para `Membro`.

***Editado de acordo com o comentário do FCCDias.***

```
var pessoas = items.ToList().Select(i =>
            {
                var membro = i as Membro;
                if(membro != null)
                {
                    return new
                    {
                        membro.Id,
                        membro.Nome,
                        Cargo = membro.Cargo
                    };
                }
                else
                {
                    return new
                    {
                        i.id,
                        i.Nome,
                        Cargo = default(Cargo)
                    };
                }
            });
```

Comment: desculpas, mas, só vai funcionar se você der antes um ToList() ou ToArray() (items.ToList().Select), e nesse modo ficaria lento, porque, se ta fazendo em Linq Objects (que não é legal se essa estrutura trazer muitos registros). Obs: o que eu to falando foi testado, e mexo no entity desde primeira versão, quando vi o seu código fui para VS testar mas, como teve que usar ToList().Select, não seria muito legal usar, funciona, mas, como eu disse para trazer muitos dados vai ficar lento. No meu exemplo foi Linq To SQL, ou seja, na própria SQL é feita as conversões e enviado direto para a variavel

Comment: É verdade, você tem razão. O `Select` de um `IQueryable` aceita uma *Expression tree*, não um lambda como eu estou fazendo. Obrigada pelo comentário.

Comment: Gostei muito do que você fez, parabéns é sempre bom compartilhar vários conhecimentos. @ramaral